# Azure Function Storage Account

Tags: azure-functions

In our solution we have three function apps, two of these run on consumption plan and one is a bit of a faff to move in to the same plan as it is used externally.. the third runs on app service plan due to it's additional needs in terms of resource, control, and connections etc.. etc..

**Q1**: Can (as in, is it ok for) all of these share the same Storage Account ?

**Q2**: if not, can at least the consumption function apps share the same storage account ?

**Q3**: Is there any risk of things interfering with one another if all (or some) function apps are configured to use the same storage account for the settings:

- AzureWebJobsDashboard
- AzureWebJobsStorage
- WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1 & Q2: It's certainly possible for multiple function apps to share the same storage account without problems. (A good example of this is when you develop multiple apps in your local environment using the Azure Storage Emulator, which acts like one storage account.) Function apps are isolated from each other, so there shouldn't be interference issues between different function apps. (Do not, however, use the same storage account for a single function app between dev and prod environments, as that will lead to unexpected behavior.)

However, be aware of bandwidth - Azure Storage has its own limits ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits)). Function apps sharing a storage account must also share this bandwidth and can end up throttling each other.

Comment: hah ok, I get that it's possible.. as I do it right now :) but want to make sure that I am not lining myself up for a problem later.. or something that if I configure our production ARM template to all share the same storage account this is 'safe' ta!!

Comment: ah, i see you have edited your answer.. i didn't receive any notification of this. Thanks for the clarifications, i think from this i will share some and not others based around which hosting plan they are on, and expected throughput, i guess my mileage may vary - thanks! 

Comment: looks like it is better to keep Azure function's own storage account needs separate from its custom storage account bindings, so that if custom data loads are heavy, it won't affect the Azure function host's performance
 
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/218

Comment: @Chuck actually i *think* it's ok to share at least ones that are on consumption plan as they create a container in the target storage account per function app anyway... something running on an app svc plan i would be inclined to isolate - this is exactly the approach i've taken 