# Dedicated or shared Storage Account for Azure Function Apps with the names less than 32 symbols

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

**Short Version**
We want to migrate to v4 and our app names are less than 32 symbols.
Should we migrate to dedicated `Storage Accounts` or not?

**Long Version**
We use `Azure Functions` v3. From start one `Storage Account` was shared between 10+ `Azure Function Apps`. It could be by luck but the names are less than 32 symbols and it is not going to change. We are not using slots as they were initially not recommended and then with no adoption time or recommendation made generally available.

Pre-question research revealed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588957/azure-functions-apps-sharing-same-storage-account-concurrency-error) question but it looks like more related to the `durable functions`. [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428455/azure-function-storage-account) question looks more up the point but outdated and the accepted answer states that one `Storage Account` can be used.

Firstly, the official documentation has a page with [storage considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations#shared-storage-accounts) and it states (props to [ijabit](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2049#issuecomment-1006632652) for pointing to it.):

> It's possible for multiple function apps to share the same storage account without any issues. For example, in Visual Studio you can develop multiple apps using the Azure Storage Emulator. In this case, the emulator acts like a single storage account. The same storage account used by your function app can also be used to store your application data. However, this approach isn't always a good idea in a production environment.

Unfortunately it does not elaborate further on the rationale behind the last sentence.
The [page with best practices](https://To%20improve%20performance%20in%20production,%20use%20a%20separate%20storage%20account%20for%20each%20function%20app.%20This%20is%20especially%20true%20with%20Durable%20Functions%20and%20Event%20Hub%20triggered%20functions.) for `Azure Function` mentions:

> To improve performance in production, use a separate storage account for each function app. This is especially true with Durable Functions and Event Hub triggered functions.

To my greater confusion there [was](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/46f493b9c532c7790f8a65eda392a0d75a7c955b/articles/azure-functions/functions-best-practices.md#avoid-sharing-storage-accounts) a subsection on this page that said "Avoid sharing storage accounts". But it was later removed.
[This](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/218) issue is somehow superficially related to the question as it mentions the recommendation in the thread.

Secondly, we had contacted Azure Support for different not-related to this question issues and the two different support engineers shared different opinions on the current issue. One said that we can share a Storage Account among Functions Apps and another one said that we should not. So the recommendation from the support was mixed.

Thirdly, we want to migrate to v4 and in the [migration notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#runtime) it is stated:

> Function apps that share storage accounts will fail to start if their computed hostnames are the same. Use a separate storage account for each function app. ([#2049](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2049))

Digging deeper into the topic, the only issue is the [collision](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2015) of the function host names that are used to obtain the lock that was known even in Oct 2017. One can follow the thread and see how in Jan 2020 the recommendation was made to update the official Azure naming recommendation but it was [made](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/9c27e391ee2cc883255e5b8d5dff33fe6fb3fc38) only on late Nov 2021. I also see that a non-intrusive, i.e. without renaming, solution is to [manually set the host id](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Host-IDs#host-id-override). The two arguments [raised](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2049#issuecomment-1007132941) by balag0 are: single point of failure and better isolation. They sound good from the perspective of cleaner architecture but pragmatically I personally find `Storage Accounts` reliable, especially if read about redundancy or consider that MS is dog-fooding it for other services. So it looks more like a backbone of Azure for me.

Finally, as we want to migrate to v4, should we migrate to dedicated `Storage Accounts` or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the large project with 30+ Azure Functions I work on, we have gone with dedicated Storage Accounts. The reason why is [Azure Storage account service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits). As the docs mention, this really comes into play with Durable Task Functions, but can also come into play in other high volume scenarios. There's a hard limit of 20k requests per second for a Storage Account. Hit that limit, and requests will fail and will return HTTP 429 responses. This means that your Azure Function invocation will fail too. We're running some high-volume scenarios and ran into this.

It can also cause problems with Durable Task Functions if two functions have the same TaskHub ID in host.json. This causes a collision when Durable Task Framework does its internal bookkeeping using Storage Queues and Table Storage, and there's lots of pain and agony as things fail in spectacular fashion.

Note that the 20k requests per second service limit can be raised with a support ticket to Azure. If approved, the max they'll raise it to is 50k requests/second.

So avoid the potential headaches and go with a Storage Account per Function.